# VB For loop karstieji(x).Location = New Point(0, a) nullreferenceException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Vb application freezes I get nullreferenceException was unhandled on new point(0 ,a) here is the code.

```
    For x = 1 To 5
        Dim karstieji(x) As Label
        Dim karstieji1(x) As Button
        Dim a As Integer
        Dim b As Integer
        a = 0
        b = 0
        Panel2.Controls.Add(karstieji(x))
        karstieji(x).Location = New Point(0, a)
        karstieji(x).Size = New Size(140, 20)
        karstieji(x).Text = "Bulvyniai blynai"
        karstieji(x).Font = New Font(1, 12)
        Panel2.Controls.Add(karstieji1(x))
        karstieji1(x).Location = New Point(140, b)
        karstieji1(x).Size = New Size(12, 12)
        a += 20
        b += 12
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use control arrays in VB.NET so the code you are trying to use will not work.

I would suggest using a generic list if you need to keep a reference to the controls:

```
'In your class
Private _labels As New List(Of Label)
Private _buttons As New List(Of Button)


'create the controls
Dim a As Integer = 0
Dim b As Integer = 0

    For x = 1 To 5
        Dim karstieji As New Label
        Dim karstieji1 As New Button
        Panel2.Controls.Add(karstieji)
        karstieji.Location = New Point(0, a)
        karstieji.Size = New Size(140, 20)
        karstieji.Text = "Bulvyniai blynai"
        karstieji.Font = New Font(1, 12)
        Panel2.Controls.Add(karstieji1)
        karstieji1.Location = New Point(140, b)
        karstieji1.Size = New Size(12, 12)
        a += 20
        b += 12
        'add a reference to the controls so you can refer to them later
        _labels.Add(karstieji)
        _buttons.Add(karstieji1)
    Next
```

Note I have also moved the `a` and `b` variables to outside the loop as these will always be zero otherwise

Comment: He should also initialse his button, otherwise a nullreference exception will occur at `karstieji1(x).Location = New Point(140, b)`

Comment: Arrays new can't be declared in arrayy. sranken How  to initialse button    karstieji1(x).Location = New Point(140, b) what to do?

Comment: See the code of Matt. It will sovle your problem :)

Comment: Matts code has nothing do do with my problem :/ nullreferenceException was unhandled on newpoint(0 , a)

Comment: You *can* use control arrays (although they don’t correspond to what’s known as “control arrays” in VB6). The error in OP’s code is that the control class wasn’t instantiated.